# Django page error. Something wrong in urls

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-urls, web-development-server

I am new to Django and learning this python framework. I have created a virtual environment called Virtual_Django_Project and installed Django in it. Moving ahead I created folder called Django_project and added an app called blog you can see my files here [File Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDliz.png). Error >[Page not found at /blog/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMjQ6.png)

**blog.views.py Code**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):

    return HttpResponse('Home')
```

**blog.urls.py Code**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name ='blog-home'),
]
```

Main **Django_Project.urls Code**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Can anyone tell me why my blog page is not opening and showing the error page not found?

PS: Server is running in cmd.

Comment: Try to reverse the order in `urlpatterns` list. Put the path() funcion for admin site in second place.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I guess, based on your screenshot it seems to look like only your admin page is properly registered.

It is very simple, just go to settings.py in project and make sure you added your apps in installed apps.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
"app name"
```

then clearly you have added urls.py in app but you have to add in project urls.py too... If you forgot it add it too...

```
urlpatterns = [
path('blog/', include('app name.urls', namespace='app name')),
```

- namespace is not a must to add.

I guess that should be the error...

Comment: Thanks for your help, But I didn't saved my files in vs code (silly me) that's what was causing the error. After saving my files it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `path` found in your `blog` app. It seems that simply you have not specified `"blog"` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. Pretty common mistake after creating a new app in a Django's project. Add it so Django would be able to find that view.

Comment: Thanks for your help, But I didn't saved my files in vs code (silly me) that's what was causing the error. After saving my files it worked well.